# Convert column value with html tags into sql view with rows and columns

Tags: html, sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table named data with a column desc_data.
The value of this column is as below :

```
<span class ="label">A</span><br> <span class ="value">A-Class</span> <span class ="label">B</span><br> <span class ="value">B-Class</span>.
```

I want to parse this column value,strip html tags and into a new view split it using sql query(Regexp_Replace maybe) such that:
All label values become columns, i.e.

`<span class ="label"> A` & `<span class ="label">B` will become *columns*, and

`<span class ="value">A-Class` & `<span class ="value">B-Class` will become the *column value* respectively.

The actual data is much more with many labels and values however this is just sample to get help.
The expected result should be:

View data_View

```
A          B
A-Class    B-Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be much more convenient to get required data as rows, not columns.
And you can parse it using xmltable with a little modification of your original html (removing unclosed tags like `<br>`. that's why `<br/>` is better):

```sql
with t as (
  -- your sample data:
  select
    q'[<span class ="label">A</span><br> <span class ="value">A-Class</span> <span class ="label">B</span><br> <span class ="value">B-Class</span>.
  ]' html_data
from dual
)
-- main query:
select xt.*
from t
    ,xmltable(
      'let $labels := /root/span[@class eq "label"]
       let $values := /root/span[@class eq "value"]
       for $label at $i in $labels
          return element label {
             attribute name {$label/text()}, 
             attribute value {$values[$i]/text()}
          }
       '
      passing
      xmltype(
       --- modify your html to make it compatible with xml:
       '<root>'
       || replace(replace(t.html_data,'<br>'),'&nbsp;')
       ||'</root>'
      )
      columns
         n for ordinality,
         label_name path '@name',
         label_value path '@value'
    ) xt;
```

Result:

```sql
         N LABEL_NAME                     LABEL_VALUE
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
         1 A                              A-Class
         2 B                              B-Class
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218028/discussion-between-vini-and-sayan-malakshinov).

Comment: Hi Sayan, when i checked for bigger and real data. At palces it is throwing error. ex: when tag is something like <span class="desc_label">Domain</span><br><span class="select desc_value" data-option_list="RAD_PIGMENT_ID" cust="Rad_Pigment_Id" style="display: block;">Production</span>     <span class="desc_label">Project Team
</span><br><span class="desc_value">Asdsh jsdja&nbsp;kajdhjahdja Grueber, Here for label domain instead of the value Production, it takes the next tag's value,i.e. Asdsh jsdja&nbsp;kajdhjahdja Grueber which should have come against Project team

Comment: basically a way to modify  let $values := /root/span[@class eq "desc_value"], so that it also includes  let $values := /root/span[@class eq " select desc_value"]

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your string by some pattern( such as `'/span> <span'` ) recursively. Extract the desired column by using `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function, and then apply pivoting :

```
WITH t(desc_data) AS
(
 SELECT '<span class ="label">A</span><br> <span class ="value">A-Class</span> <span class ="label">B</span><br> <span class ="value">B-Class</span> <span class ="label">C</span><br> <span class ="value">C-Class</span>'
   FROM dual
), t2 AS
(
SELECT SUBSTR(desc_data,1,CASE WHEN INSTR(desc_data,'/span> <span',1,level) > 0
                               THEN INSTR(desc_data,'/span> <span',1,level) + 5 
                               ELSE LENGTH(desc_data)
                           END
             ) AS desc_data2
  FROM t
 CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(desc_data,'/span> <span') + 1
)
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(desc_data2,'(.*"label">)(\S+)(</span>.*)','\2') AS label,
          REGEXP_REPLACE(desc_data2,'(.*"value">)(\S+)(</span>.*)','\2') AS value
     FROM t2 )
 PIVOT ( MAX(VALUE) FOR LABEL IN ('A' AS "A", 'B' AS "B", 'C' AS "C") );


A          B          C
-------    -------    -------
A-Class    B-Class    C-Class
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4065d57700d91d417565f612d1a2aee9)</kbd>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218034/discussion-between-vini-and-barbaros-ozhan).